# How to search and highlight every occurrence of a string in a context

Tags: javascript, php, string

I want to search and highlight the query string a user search for within a context if there's match for this string, I'm not too good using Javascript i can achieve the same function in php but i need it to be done with javascrip
Say i have say I have a query string `Hello world` and i have 3 context where there's match say `1. hello world it's new day today` `2. welcome to my world` `3. say hello to the new world` in this 3 context what i want is when a user submit a query with hellow world i want to highlight `hello world` in the first context, `world` in the second context and `hello` in the third context, with php i do the following and it matches as expected

```
function highlight_word( $content, $words, $cssClassName) {
     $q = explode(" ", $words);
     for($i =0; $i < count($q); $i++){
      $word = $q[$i];       
      $replace = "<span class='".$cssClassName."'>" . $word . '</span>'; // create replacement 
      $content = str_ireplace( $word, $replace, $content ); // replace content
     }
     return $content; // return highlighted data
 }
```

Now i try to use this same idea in javascript but i found that it doesn't work how i want it.

```
This first code will only match a context that has exactly the search string in the case it will match context number 1 and will not match the other



  String.prototype.replaceAll = function(searchStr) {
    var content;
    var str = this;
    var replaceStr ;

       //replace any occurence of the str with an highligthed version of the same str
       replaceStr = "<span class='kwHighlight'>"+searchStr+"</span>";
       // escape regexp special characters in search string
    searchStr = searchStr.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
    content = str.replace(new RegExp(searchStr, 'gi'), replaceStr);

    return content;
};
```

this second code will only match the last occurrence string in the context which means world will be highlighted in all the context where there's occurence

```
 String.prototype.replaceAll = function(searchStr) {
    var content;
    var str = this;
    var replaceStr ;
    //split the searchStr into an array
    var searchStrArray = searchStr.split(" ");
    for(var i=0; i <searchStrArray.length; i++){
       var replaceQ = searchStrArray[i]; 
       //replace any occurence of the str with an highligthed version of the same str
       replaceStr = "<span class='kwHighlight'>"+replaceQ+"</span>";
       // escape regexp special characters in search string
    searchStr = searchStrArray[i].replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
    content = str.replace(new RegExp(searchStr, 'gi'), replaceStr);
    }

    return content;
};
```

Any help on how i can actualize this thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below snippet, If you don't want to match the whole phrase use `${keyword.split(" ").join("|")}` instead of the regex in the snippet.

```js
function replace(str, keyword, className) {
  let regex = `${keyword}|${keyword.split(" ").join("|")}`;
  str = str.replace(new RegExp(`${regex}`, 'ig'), (w) => {
    return `<span class="${className}">${w}</span>`;
  });
  return str;
}

console.log(replace("welcome to my hello world and this is my world of hello", "hello world", "MyClass"));
```

Comment: In case you need a function that is compatible in old browsers,

`function replace(str, keyword, className) {
  var regex = keyword + "|" + keyword.split(" ").join("|");
  str = str.replace(new RegExp("" + regex, "ig"), function(w) {
    return '<span class="' + className + '">' + w + "</span>";
  });
  return str;
}`

Answer (score 2):

if you want to execute this in javascript instead of jQuery, try this

```js
function myFunction() {
      var contexts = document.getElementById('contexts').getElementsByTagName('p');
      var query_string = document.getElementById('query_string').value;
      if (query_string) {
        for (let i = 0; i < contexts.length; i++) {
          contexts[i].innerHTML = contexts[i].textContent;
          let string = contexts[i].innerHTML;
          let regex = `${query_string}|${query_string.split(" ").join("|")}`;
          string = string.replace(new RegExp(`${regex}`, 'ig'), (t) => {
            return `<span class="highlight">${t}</span>`;
          });
          contexts[i].innerHTML = string;
        }
      }
  }
```

```css
.highlight {
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="query_string">
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" id="submit">Submit</button>
    <div id="contexts">
      <p>1. hello world it's new day today</p>
      <p>2. welcome to my world</p>
      <p>3. say hello to the new world</p>
    </div>
```